# no such file or directory error. What is wrong?

Tags: c, linux, makefile, module, kernel

I'm trying to build a kernel module. I'm on fedora 25

Here is my Makefile:

```
obj-m += simple.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

This is the simple.c file:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

/* This function is called when the module is loaded. */
int simple_init(void)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Module\n");

   return 0;
}

/* This function is called when the module is removed. */
void simple_exit(void) {
printk(KERN_INFO "Removing Module\n");
}

/* Macros for registering module entry and exit points. */
module_init( simple_init );
module_exit( simple_exit );

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple Module");
MODULE_AUTHOR("SGG");
```

The error I'm getting after using the make command:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.11.3-202.fc25.x86_64/build M=/home/nubian/Downloads/ch02/ch2 modules
make[1]: *** /lib/modules/4.11.3-202.fc25.x86_64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: `/lib/modules/4.11.3-202.fc25.x86_64/build` should be a link to the directory where your kernel modules are built.  Is it?  See http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.9.33/source/README#L124

Comment: This is the message I get when I try to install kernel-devel:    Last metadata expiration check: 1:09:07 ago on Mon Jun 19 12:26:54 2017.
Package kernel-devel-4.11.5-200.fc25.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.

Comment: Note that you're running kernel `4.11.3-202.fc25`, but you've installed package `kernel-devel-4.11.5-200.fc25`.  These do not match, so your build cannot succeed.  Maybe you've updated your packages to a newer kernel but have not yet rebooted your system, so you're not actually running that kernel?

Comment: @MadScientist I also think that is my problem so I ran the following: 
sudo yum install "kernel-devel-uname-r == $(uname -r)"
but it says there is no such package available...

Comment: Did you mean `yum install kernel-devel-$(uname -r)`?  I don't know what the `uname -r ==` thing is in your comment.  Anyway, I use Debian not Fedora so I can't help with the syntax for `yum`.  Maybe someone else knows the right syntax.  The simplest thing to do would be to update all your packages (particularly your kernel package) to the latest versions then reboot.  Then they should all have the same version.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `$(MAKE)` never `make` when you invoke a recursive make.  However that's not your problem.

Your problem is that you don't have the module build environment for your currently-running kernel installed.  If you install it, it will create the directories you need to build modules for your kernel.

See, for example, the `yum install` command on [this page](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Core/6/html/Release_Notes/ar01s07s07.html).

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I've already installed the kernel-devel package and I still have the same error message.

Comment: Then your running kernel must not be a normally-installed Fedora kernel.  The `$(shell uname -r)` command returns the currently-running kernel's version and that's the directory the makefile is trying to find.